# Проблема с JS. Некорректный результат запроса

Tags: ajax, javascript

Есть AJAX запрос:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"files/chek/testMail.php",
    type:"GET",
    data:"email=" + elem,
    cache:false,
    success:function(response) {
        if (response == "no") {
            showMessage('Ошибка', 'Email занят!');
            $("#email").css("background", "#D25340").fadeIn(400);
        } else {
            $("#email").css("background", "").fadeIn(400);
        }
    }
});
```

после идёт:

```
if (elem.length == 0) checkError( showMessage('Ошибка', 'Введите пароль!') );
```

И даже если в проверке Email выдаёт ошибку, скрипт все равно выполняется.
Я так понимаю, что всё что находится в success: `function(response){}` работает только в приделах запроса... Я пробовал в этой ф-ции загнать значение в переменную - не работает. В общем нужно сделать так, что если при проверке email выдаёт ошибку, то скрипт дальше не выполняется.

Comment: function checkError (field, str){
 document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = str;
 check = false;
}

Comment: Загоните то, что не должно выполняться, в success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

функция в теле $.ajax отрабатывает после того как получен ответ сервера. В вашем случае надо сделать примерно следующее:

```
function checkError() {
    //при нажатии на кнопку отправки вызываем эту функцию
    //тут мы уже делаем некую проверку.. например у нас в процесе
    //отработки этой функции инициализируется переменная checkResult 
    if(checkResult === true) {
        $.ajax.... //уже тут делаем ajax запрос
    }
    else {
        //тут можем както оповестить пользователя о ошибке
    }
}
```